# Remove duplicate contact information

Tags: contacts

After merging contacts from different sources like Facebook, Twitter, Exchange and Google+, it was apparent to me that now my contacts contain a lot of duplicate information such as the same email addresses, birthday date, website address.

Ideally, all those redundant entries should be merged as well so not to clutter things.

I've looked almost everywhere but could only find information relative to just merging issues with contacts.

(If it matters, I am using Android 2.3.)

Comment: I have the same problem. All applications I have found are only joining contacts (kind of linking), but there is no real merge option. I would also prefer an option without necessity to upload all my friend parsonal information to google ...

Answer (score 5):

[image: screen shot from Google Contacts]

Visit the [Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/) app in a desktop browser and sign in with your Google account with which your device is getting synced.  Once done (you should have successfully synced your contacts before this), the more button (as seen in the image) has option to merge.

Comment: This is not my issue; The contacts ARE merged, but information like email, birthday etc, are duplicate because they come from different sources.

Comment: I do not have any other apps to identify and merge. But having taken your contacts to Google's contact page (as above), you can edit (at least it will be better than doing in phone) to merge manually. You may also consider to export it to some other formats (like CSV) and write a small Excel macro to accomplish the task.